# Streaming data visualization in R

Tags: r, streaming, data-visualization

It looks simple but am struggling with it. Basically I am trying to visualize (plot) a simulated streaming data that comes in every two seconds i.e. for the plot to be continuous in real-time.

I have seen Microsoft Azure (but i don't have the expensive subscription). I have also seen the Animation package but it has to read in all the data before rendering the display. Is there a way to achieve this in R (or perhaps python)?
    This is what I have done so far in R:

```
    #simulate some sensor data
time <- seq(1,200,2)
sensor <- runif(100,1,100)
timedf <- data.frame(cbind(time,sensor))
timedf$time <- as.POSIXct(timedf$time,origin = "2016-05-05")

plot(timedf$time,timedf$sensor,type = "l")

#I want to visualize or plot the data continously every 2 seconds
#sleep function
mysleep <- function(x)
{
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x)
  proc.time() - p1 
}

for(i in 1:nrow(timedf)){ 
  mysleep(2)
  print(timedf[i,])
  plot(timedf[i,]$time,timedf[i,]$sensor,type = "l")
  par(new=FALSE)
}[![some sensor data][1]][1]
```

Comment: Have a look at https://plot.ly/streaming/

Comment: Thanks Steven. I have done that but it needs one to connect to their cluster and their are some pricing attached. I need something that can be done locally on a machine, wrapped around a browser for a demonstration. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do it for free if you don't mind your data being publicly available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration using `nodejs`:

```
#clone the nodejs plotly github directory
git clone https://github.com/plotly/plotly-nodejs.git
```

Edit the `examples/config.json` file using your [API credentials](https://plot.ly/settings/api) and then simply run one of the demo provided (in this example; `signal-stream.js`)

`node signal-stream.js`

Which will output a JSON string in the form of:

```
{ streamstatus: 'All Streams Go!', 
  url: 'https://plot.ly/~voxnonecho/194',
  message: '',
  warning: '',
  filename: 'streamSimpleSensor',
  error: '' }
```

Then simply follow the URL provided:

[image]

Comment: Steven, I have done it on ubuntu but when I run this command "node signal-stream.js", i don't get any response even when I have changed to the required directory. Is there something am missing?

Comment: What is your output ? Do you have `nodejs` installed properly ?

Comment: Thanks Steven. I solve the problem by installing plotly and random-signal locally (without the -g argument) into the same example directory.

Comment: The question was about achieving real-time plots in R